# Circuit with capacitor and battery- why same voltage?

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance

If we connect a capacitor and a battery in the same circuit, what makes the charge move until the voltage on the capacitor is the same as voltage on battery?

Comment: Why do charges move? Next, why would they stop moving?

Comment: @JonCuster Charges move due to electrical field. They stop moving after the electrical fields from the capacitor and battery cancel each other.
correct?

Comment: And if there is not net field, what does that mean about the voltages on the two?

Comment: @JonCuster  then integral of E*ds  along path from positive plate to positive side of battery is zero, means the same potential at both sides is the same. And the same goes if we do E*ds from negative plate to negative side of battery. 
So they have same potential difference = same voltage.